# QGIS from conda-forge won't open on OSX 11.6 (Big Sur)

Tags: qgis, gdal, osx, conda

Installing QGIS using conda and conda-forge works really well on Windows and Linux (it includes a file driver not normally included with other installs), but for some reason on my MacBook QGIS won't open. The install works fine, running produced no errors and the icon appears in the dock but no window is created.

```
conda create -n qgis -c conda-forge qgis
conda activate qgis
qgis
```

Tried on clean install of the latest miniconda3 with OSX fully up to date. Has anyone else found/solved this?

Answer (score 0):

As per answer to my GitHub issue (https://github.com/conda-forge/qgis-feedstock/issues/207), you can solve this by running/setting:

```
export QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER=1
```

which worked for me on the conda-forge distribution of QGIS 3.18